# mp4 to mpeg TS 2

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion

I want to convert mp4 video to mpeg Ts2. What's the best way to do it and preserve HD quality?

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'How to Get the Newest Smartphones from AT&T - YouTube.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2013-09-12 01:05:48
  Duration: 00:01:03.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1358 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1163 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 48k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-09-12 01:05:49
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
```

Answer (score 5):

You can re-mux to TS container by using [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) since this container [supports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats) the formats from the input.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb output.ts
```

Since it's basically "copying and pasting" and not re-encoding there will be no quality loss and it will be very quick to complete.